# Presto convert a timestamp without time zone to epoch

Tags: timestamp, presto

For example I have a time string '2012-10-31 01:00' (it's UTC but the string itself doesn't have the timezone code in it)

How do I convert it to the epoch big integer?

I have tried many versions, just no luck.

```
SELECT from_unixtime(cast('2012-10-31 01:00' as timestamp), 'Etc/UTC')
ERROR: function from_unixtime(timestamp without time zone, unknown) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 8
```

And

```
SELECT from_unixtime('2012-10-31 01:00', 'Etc/UTC')
```

Same error

Answer (score 4):

- Start with converting to `timestamp`: `CAST('2012-10-31 01:00' AS timestamp)`
- then make `timestamp with time zone`: [`... AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#time-zone-conversion)
- then convert to epoch seconds (`double`): [`to_unixtime`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#to_unixtime)
- then convert to epoch millis (`bigint`): `CAST(... * 1000 AS bigint)`.

Everything combined:

```
presto:default> SELECT CAST(to_unixtime(CAST('2012-10-31 01:00' AS timestamp) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') * 1000 AS bigint);
     _col0
---------------
 1351641600000
(1 row)
```

(Tested on Presto 320)

You can skip the `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` conversion for now, but once we [fix Presto timestamp semantics](https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/37), this will be needed. Thus I recommend having this in your query.